# Input stream in android

Tags: android

I am making an HTTP get request to a website for an android application I am making.

I am using a DefaultHttpClient and using HttpGet to issue the request. I get the entity response and from this obtain an InputStream object for getting the html of the page.

The source file is:
http://www.textfixer.com/resources/dropdowns/country-list-iso-codes.txt

And my code it's:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count = in.read(buffer);
while (count >= 0) {
        bo.write(buffer);
        count = in.read(buffer);
}

String s = bo.toString();

final Vector<String> str = new Vector<String>();
String[] line = s.split("\n");
int index = 0;
while (index < line.length) {
        str.add(line[index]);
        index++;
}
```

But in the output after the corrected list of countries this code added this string, why?

```
    ZW:Zimbabweaint Pierre and Miquelon
    VC:Saint Vincent and The Grenadines
    WS:Samoa
    SM:San Marino
    ST:Sao Tome and Principe
    SA:Saudi Arabia
    SN:Senegal
    RS:Serbia
    SC:Seychelles
    SL:Sierra Leone
    SG:Singapore
    SK:Slovakia
    SI:Slovenia
    SB:Solomon Islands
    SO:Somalia
    ZA:South Africa
    GS:South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands
    ES:Spain
    LK:Sri Lanka
    SD:Sudan
    SR:Suriname
    SJ:Svalbard and Jan Mayen
    SZ:Swaziland
    SE:Sweden
    CH:Switzerland
    SY:Syrian Arab Republic
    TW:Taiwan, Province of China
    TJ:Tajikistan
    TZ:Tanzania, United Republic of
    TH:Thailand
    TL:Timor-leste
    TG:Togo
    TK:Tokelau
    TO:Tonga
    TT:Trinidad and Tobago
    TN:Tunisia
    TR:Turkey
    TM:Turkmenistan
    TC:Turks and Caicos Islands
    TV:Tuvalu
    UG:Uganda
    UA:Ukraine
    AE:United Arab Emirates
    GB



EDIT:
the output:

AF:Afghanistan
AX:Åland Islands
AL:Albania
DZ:Algeria
AS:American Samoa
AD:Andorra
AO:Angola
AI:Anguilla
AQ:Antarctica
AG:Antigua and Barbuda
AR:Argentina
AM:Armenia
AW:Aruba
AU:Australia
AT:Austria
AZ:Azerbaijan
BS:Bahamas
BH:Bahrain
BD:Bangladesh
BB:Barbados
BY:Belarus
BE:Belgium
BZ:Belize
BJ:Benin
BM:Bermuda
BT:Bhutan
BO:Bolivia
BA:Bosnia and Herzegovina
BW:Botswana
BV:Bouvet Island
BR:Brazil
IO:British Indian Ocean Territory
BN:Brunei Darussalam
BG:Bulgaria
BF:Burkina Faso
BI:Burundi
KH:Cambodia
CM:Cameroon
CA:Canada
CV:Cape Verde
KY:Cayman Islands
CF:Central African Republic
TD:Chad
CL:Chile
CN:China
CX:Christmas Island
CC:Cocos (Keeling) Islands
CO:Colombia
KM:Comoros
CG:Congo
CD:Congo, The Democratic Republic of The
CK:Cook Islands
CR:Costa Rica
CI:Cote D'ivoire
HR:Croatia
CU:Cuba
CY:Cyprus
CZ:Czech Republic
DK:Denmark
DJ:Djibouti
DM:Dominica
DO:Dominican Republic
EC:Ecuador
EG:Egypt
SV:El Salvador
GQ:Equatorial Guinea
ER:Eritrea
EE:Estonia
ET:Ethiopia
FK:Falkland Islands (Malvinas)
FO:Faroe Islands
FJ:Fiji
FI:Finland
FR:France
GF:French Guiana
PF:French Polynesia
TF:French Southern Territories
GA:Gabon
GM:Gambia
GE:Georgia
DE:Germany
GH:Ghana
GI:Gibraltar
GR:Greece
GL:Greenland
GD:Grenada
GP:Guadeloupe
GU:Guam
GT:Guatemala
GG:Guernsey
GN:Guinea
GW:Guinea-bissau
GY:Guyana
HT:Haiti
HM:Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands
VA:Holy See (Vatican City State)
HN:Honduras
HK:Hong Kong
HU:Hungary
IS:Iceland
IN:India
ID:Indonesia
IR:Iran, Islamic Republic of
IQ:Iraq
IE:Ireland
IM:Isle of Man
IL:Israel
IT:Italy
JM:Jamaica
JP:Japan
JE:Jersey
JO:Jordan
KZ:Kazakhstan
KE:Kenya
KI:Kiribati
KP:Korea, Democratic People's Republic of
KR:Korea, Republic of
KW:Kuwait
KG:Kyrgyzstan
LA:Lao People's Democratic Republic
LV:Latvia
LB:Lebanon
LS:Lesotho
LR:Liberia
LY:Libyan Arab Jamahiriya
LI:Liechtenstein
LT:Lithuania
LU:Luxembourg
MO:Macao
MK:Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of
MG:Madagascar
MW:Malawi
MY:Malaysia
MV:Maldives
ML:Mali
MT:Malta
MH:Marshall Islands
MQ:Martinique
MR:Mauritania
MU:Mauritius
YT:Mayotte
MX:Mexico
FM:Micronesia, Federated States of
MD:Moldova, Republic of
MC:Monaco
MN:Mongolia
ME:Montenegro
MS:Montserrat
MA:Morocco
MZ:Mozambique
MM:Myanmar
NA:Namibia
NR:Nauru
NP:Nepal
NL:Netherlands
AN:Netherlands Antilles
NC:New Caledonia
NZ:New Zealand
NI:Nicaragua
NE:Niger
NG:Nigeria
NU:Niue
NF:Norfolk Island
MP:Northern Mariana Islands
NO:Norway
OM:Oman
PK:Pakistan
PW:Palau
PS:Palestinian Territory, Occupied
PA:Panama
PG:Papua New Guinea
PY:Paraguay
PE:Peru
PH:Philippines
PN:Pitcairn
PL:Poland
PT:Portugal
PR:Puerto Rico
QA:Qatar
RE:Reunion
RO:Romania
RU:Russian Federation
RW:Rwanda
SH:Saint Helena
KN:Saint Kitts and Nevis
LC:Saint Lucia
PM:Saint Pierre and Miquelon
VC:Saint Vincent and The Grenadines
WS:Samoa
SM:San Marino
ST:Sao Tome and Principe
SA:Saudi Arabia
SN:Senegal
RS:Serbia
SC:Seychelles
SL:Sierra Leone
SG:Singapore
SK:Slovakia
SI:Slovenia
SB:Solomon Islands
SO:Somalia
ZA:South Africa
GS:South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands
ES:Spain
LK:Sri Lanka
SD:Sudan
SR:Suriname
SJ:Svalbard and Jan Mayen
SZ:Swaziland
SE:Sweden
CH:Switzerland
SY:Syrian Arab Republic
TW:Taiwan, Province of China
TJ:Tajikistan
TZ:Tanzania, United Republic of
TH:Thailand
TL:Timor-leste
TG:Togo
TK:Tokelau
TO:Tonga
TT:Trinidad and Tobago
TN:Tunisia
TR:Turkey
TM:Turkmenistan
TC:Turks and Caicos Islands
TV:Tuvalu
UG:Uganda
UA:Ukraine
AE:United Arab Emirates
GB:United Kingdom
US:United States
UM:United States Minor Outlying Islands
UY:Uruguay
UZ:Uzbekistan
VU:Vanuatu
VE:Venezuela
VN:Viet Nam
VG:Virgin Islands, British
VI:Virgin Islands, U.S.
WF:Wallis and Futuna
EH:Western Sahara
YE:Yemen
ZM:Zambia

//this is incorrectly

ZW:Zimbabweaint Pierre and Miquelon
VC:Saint Vincent and The Grenadines
WS:Samoa
SM:San Marino
ST:Sao Tome and Principe
SA:Saudi Arabia
SN:Senegal
RS:Serbia
SC:Seychelles
SL:Sierra Leone
SG:Singapore
SK:Slovakia
SI:Slovenia
SB:Solomon Islands
SO:Somalia
ZA:South Africa
GS:South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands
ES:Spain
LK:Sri Lanka
SD:Sudan
SR:Suriname
SJ:Svalbard and Jan Mayen
SZ:Swaziland
SE:Sweden
CH:Switzerland
SY:Syrian Arab Republic
TW:Taiwan, Province of China
TJ:Tajikistan
TZ:Tanzania, United Republic of
TH:Thailand
TL:Timor-leste
TG:Togo
TK:Tokelau
TO:Tonga
TT:Trinidad and Tobago
TN:Tunisia
TR:Turkey
TM:Turkmenistan
TC:Turks and Caicos Islands
TV:Tuvalu
UG:Uganda
UA:Ukraine
AE:United Arab Emirates
GB
```

Comment: What is the problem? Remember logcat have a string limit -- P.S Avoid `Vector`. Anyway you could read from the HTTP page line by line and add elements directly

Comment: post the outputting code.

Comment: The problem is on output because I've the list incorrectly because the code has duplicate some strings

Comment: Ok njzk2, I've edit the post